# How to set confirm message for reset button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my current code:

`<%= button_tag "Reset", type: :reset, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`

which generates:

`<button name="button" type="reset" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Reset</button>`

The confirm message doesn’t show at all. So I have to change to this:

`<button type="reset" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" />`

This one works! But is there any way I can do this in a more railsy way?

If I remove `type: :reset`, the message shows but that obviously is not what I want to do.

Comment: What is the parentheses here: ` data: { confirm: "Are you sure?") }` a typo?

Comment: @Rubioli Thank you. I have removed that.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
<%= button_tag( :type => 'reset', :class => "btn", :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }) do %>
Reset
<% end %>
```

*I have tested in on rails 4.2.4 and it works fine.*

Comment: Sorry for the typo but I don't have the typo in my real code. I tried copy and pasting your both examples but they don't work. The first one doesn't show any alert message. The second one gave me an error `unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting ')'`

Comment: sorry @Wit now I had a type haha. can you try the first one once again. I forgot the parentheses

Comment: It doesn't work even with your edited answer :( BTW, I use Rails 5 if that matters.

Comment: hm, not sure if its a Rails 4 related issue. I tested it with rails 4.2.4 and works perfectly. One thing though, you can also use `link_to`. If you dont want to redirect to any page. you can just do Prevent default. Does confirmation for your `link_to`s works? if yes I can add another aswer

Comment: Please provide an example here. But I don't think we can use `type: :reset` with `link_to`, can we?

Comment: @Wit to be correct, what is this reset button will do? whats its purpose and where its located?